# How can we use elasticsearch for time-series data? I want to use Elastic-Stack as a whole for Time-Series Data

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, elastic-stack, elk

I know about prometheus, influxdb etc. But what i really need is to use Elasticsearch for a time-series data itself

I have got this blog which explains a bit but since **mappings** are been deprecated in version 6 and above how do i use **elasticsearch** for a **time**-**series** **data** with ES V6.0 or the latest version

https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-time-series-data-store

Comment: mappings are not deprecated, only document type

Comment: That's a very broad question with no definitive answer. To even get close to answering the question, a blog post is probably required. There is really no "how," as there is nothing special you need to do to store time series data. It pretty much just comes down to optimizing your indices for this kind of data. You will probably want to create daily/weekly/monthly indices based on how many documents you need to store (e.g. `access-logs-*`). You can also consider setting the `index` parameter to `false` for fields you don't need to filter on. As mentioned, only mapping types are being removed.

Comment: @dejanmarich https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html. This link suggests that the mappings are been deprecated. But in the given link they've talked about removal of mapping types. Is types and mapping types one and the same?

Comment: @ba0708 Can you please refer me some sites/blogs to actually know what and how exactly can i optimize indices and what other things do i need? Thanks!